# In command prompt, why does ^G ring only once, when I could write it three times?

Tags: python-2.7, console, command-prompt

Along with Python's "\a" for some reason, my computer will only ring its bell once. I've done echo control g (three ^G) and it will make one sound, not three. How come? I have Windows 10

Comment: Does a group of three make a duration three times as long as one?  In order to have a sequence of three beeps rather than a sustained sound, you'll have to cause a delay in between.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Just tried that- does not affect the duration of the sound, but triples the time for the sound to start. Tried with several, just a delay before the one beep happened.